# How to update Lenovo BIOS on a T460 without battery?

Tags: laptop, bios, battery, thinkpad

I am trying to update my Lenovo T460 bios to latest version:

Version 1.43.1.11 (https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t460/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI).

Normally it is not a problem to update the BIOS but my battery is dead (and can't order a new one due to COVID-19 in my location) and the update tool says I need the battery to be charged.

Do you know of any switches like Dell BIOS typically has, i.e.

```
/forceit
```

Comment: have you checked if AliExpress ships to you? i'd be surprised if they didn't, https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10000293658276.html

Comment: You might be able to fool it by putting DC power on the correct battery pins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lenovo requires a working battery, decent charge (at least half) and plugged into AC.  This is to prevent possibly bricking the BIOS chip. There is not a facility within the Lenovo BIOS update application (and looking through the documentation) to update with no battery.

I have done lots of Lenovo (and IBM) BIOS updates for myself and for clients.

I have ordered parts during COVID. Try Lenovo Sales Support and also 3rd party suppliers with warranty approved parts.

Comment: Hi John - thanks for the reply. I know that the risk of bricking the machine but that is not my question. I am in a remote place in Africa and here it is not possible to order for the next foreseeable future unfortunately.

Comment: I edited my answer to amplify the point that no switch is available to update without a battery.

Comment: This is the official Lenovo answer BUT it is possible.Though Lenovo try to avoid flashin without complying with their rules, it is possible to flash BIOS/ECP without battery check. See my answer below

Comment: I do not know who or why this was downvoted - the answer is accurate

Answer (score 11):

After a month searching the internet, I finally got my Yoga X1 Gen2 bios updated without battery. It was much more simple than I thought.

- download the official bios on lenovo support page and extract it.
- Run WINUPTP64.EXE or WINUPTP.EXE using command line with "-sp" option.

In my case, in CMD, I typed: `C:\DRIVERS\FLASH\n1nuj30w\20210302.08305818/WINUPTP64.EXE -sp`

Command line options:

```
   "  -s        ... Silent mode\n"
   "  -r        ... Reboot after program completed\n"
   "  -sp       ... Skip power status check\n"
   "  -chk      ... Check current TPM firmware\n"
   "  -suc password ... Skip user confirmation at startup\n\n"
   " Note: -suc option requires supervisor password.\n"
```

source: https://thinkdeploy.blogspot.com/2017/11/tpm-firmware-update-utility.html

Comment: Does not work, because the `-sp` option is for TpmUpdt64.exe, not for WINUPTP.exe.

Comment: `-sp` worked like a charm for me with `WINUPTP64.EXE`.

Comment: I needed to change into  the directory by executing `cd C:\DRIVERS\FLASH\n1nuj30w\20210302.08305818/` and then executing `WINUPTP64.EXE -sp` from there

Answer (score 4):

Following info and steps worked in my old lenovo

The bios zip file includes:

- 2 files .FL1(BIOS) and .FL2 (ECP: Embedded Controller Program / platform)
- executables with a name similar to winphlash (can be DOS or windows)

winphlash can backup current BIOS and apply a BIOS with extension .ROM and will not check for battery.

The .FL files have the format required by winphlash, so you can rename the extension FL1 to ROM or just force the filter to pick the FL file

**I managed to Flash the FL1(BIOS) and it is recognized and works.**

**However** I didn't know what to do with FL2 file, I tried to flash as i did with BIOS but I received a warning message saying that version and code is not the expected.

(update: [ECP should always be flashed before than BIOS](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/BIOS_Upgrade#Two_Firmwares:_BIOS_and_ECP))

Anyway, despite the message I flashed the ECP/platform ROM and everything worked well.

BTW I don't consider buying a new battery the best solution.
Because in the practise not all people need a battery and for old laptops the cost can be similar to the laptop price.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you elaborate on which Lenovo model you have, and also what bios file you used?

Comment: @Sha i applied on a X61 but the procedure should be similar for other lenovo laptops. Unfortunately I have not a modern lenovo to verify.  there is good BIOS Upgrade info in  https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/BIOS_Upgrade

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the only related thread: For the **Lenovo Ideapad 120S-14IAP** I had to go to the `BIOS` folder and edit the `default.rsp` file by changing the line `/cbp 20` to `/cbp 0`.

I assume that `cbp` stands for something like charge battery percentage, and that the default minimum level is 20%.

Comment: Nicely spotted. I'm not sure that file is available for my old T460 but will definitely give a go next time it becomes relevant.

Answer (score 1):

On **Lenovo ThinkPad X230i** was enough to copy BIOS (`*.FL1`) and ECP (`*.FL2`) files to parent folder, where `WinFlash64.exe` is located then run `cmd.exe` as administrator and enter command:

```
> cd <path/to/WinFlash64.exe>
> WinFlash64.exe /file $01D3000.FL1
```

where `$01D3000.FL1` was my BIOS file. ECP had the same name but "the next" extension like `$01D3000.FL2` and it was probably taken automatically based on numeric pattern.